# Copy value from class member to be used in calculation (design suggestions)

Tags: c#, copy, ref

I was wondering what best practice is for working with numerical variables that are contained as fields on a class. Say that i have a class "MyClassWithNumber" which contains a field "InputNumber" that i want to use in a calculation. Example:

```
public double MyCalculationMethod(MyClassWithNumber instanceOfObject)
{
    double MyDouble1 = instanceOfObject.InputNumber;
    double MyDouble2 = instanceOfObject.InputNumber;

    // .. Do some iterated calculation with starting values as above
    // .. that modifies reference to InputNumber.

    return EndCalculation;
}
```

In a case like this, i will modify the value in MyClassWithNumber, which i may not be interested in. Ideally, i quess i want to make a copy of the value in my class.

Can anyone suggest some good design patterns for handling cases like this?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're describing.  Can you provide a simple but complete example?

Comment: why does the method need the entire class instance if it is only concerned with one value?

Comment: Alright, in this case i can see why you could just pass the parameter, but for more advanced applications you might need other fields from the class i quess (in which case it's easiest just to pass it)

Comment: In either case, why isnt that a method in the class since all the data is in/from/contained in the class.  Pass data the class *doesnt* have in (then ask why it doesnt have it if it needs it)